# Scale UP SpagoBI application with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, scalability, business-intelligence, spagobi

I have SpagoBI 5.1 application running on tomcat on my server.

I would like to know how that can be Scaled UP Horizontally as well as Vertically ant at what extent.

So please guide.

Comment: Interesting question. The answer would  be helpful to me as well. So, I'll ask SpagoBI paid support and share the answer.

Comment: Hi David, any update on the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are paraphrased suggestions from Spago Support

- Install DBMS in highly available mode
- Create a single database for the SpagoBI Server metadata db
- Setup a cluster environment for SpagoBI Servers.The cluster should have two or more nodes.Each SpagoBI Server will run a separate Tomcat, so no session data is shared.
- Add a web server (such as Apache) as a load balancer, configuring Apache in the session affinity.That allows a user to login into a SpagoBI server and stay directed to that server in the cluster for the user's session.

Comment: can you explain how can I work with point 4 i.e Apache for load balancer

Comment: I suggest looking into Apache web server's mod_proxy_balancer . Documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html